# get values for a polynomical function from excel in java

Tags: java, excel, function

I have a chart in excel that represents some value over a one day period. So I add the reference function and I get something like this:

```
y = 1E-13x6 - 2E-10x5 + 8E-08x4 - 1E-05x3 + 0,0004x2 + 0,0275x + 8,414
```

A mesure in my data set is:

```
09:36:21 => 5,27
```

The firts thing I need to know is how to transform the timestamp into a value to give to the function. After some cell value transforming I've found out that excel gives timestamps a representation between 0.00000 and 0.99999, so for example 09:36:21 is 0.400243055555556. Then I've coded a little java test script:

```
double x = 0.400243055555556;
double x6 = (1*Math.pow(10, -13))*Math.pow(x, 6);
double x5 = (2*Math.pow(10, -10))*Math.pow(x, 5);
double x4 = (8*Math.pow(10, -8))*Math.pow(x, 4);
double x3 = (1*Math.pow(10, -5))*Math.pow(x, 3);
double x2 = (4*Math.pow(10, -4))*Math.pow(x, 2);
double y = x6 - x5 + x4 - x3 + x2 + 0.0275*x + 8.414;
```

But after executing this script I get y = 8.425070122712738. So this is obviously not working. I must say that all the values in the chart range from 5 to 12.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't know what. Maybe I've coded the function badly, or maybe the x I'm choosing is not a right value, but something is wrong. Can anyone help?

Update: My code wasn't that good, what duffymo suggested worked better. But the problem was that Excel was giving my the wrong tendendy line. I've managed to get the good one using a scatter graph.

Comment: Your initial assumption must have a problem, how could it be a number between 0 and 1 when you are adding 8.414 to it, and all the other variables are -1<x<1?

Comment: The x values are between 0 and 1 (from what I've deduced seeing how excel converts timestamps), and the y values I'm expecting range from 5 to 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend coding it this way - roundoff could be an issue.

I would recommend [Horner scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme):

I coded it this way and got the same answer that you did:

```
public class Horner
{
   public static final NumberFormat DEFAULT_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double [] a = { 8.414, 0.0275, 0.0004, -1.0e-5, 8.0e-8, -2.0e-10, 1.0e-13 };
      for (double x = 0.0; x < 1.0;  x += 0.05)
      {
         double y = a[0] + x*(a[1] + x*(a[2] + x*(a[3] + x*(a[4] + x*(a[5])))));
         System.out.println("x = " + DEFAULT_FORMAT.format(x) + " y = " + DEFAULT_FORMAT.format(y));
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the result I get.  The higher order terms aren't doing much good; the coefficients are small, and when you raise a fraction to a power it diminishes the effect even more.

```
x = 0.000 y = 8.414
x = 0.050 y = 8.415
x = 0.100 y = 8.417
x = 0.150 y = 8.418
x = 0.200 y = 8.420
x = 0.250 y = 8.421
x = 0.300 y = 8.422
x = 0.350 y = 8.424
x = 0.400 y = 8.425
x = 0.450 y = 8.426
x = 0.500 y = 8.428
x = 0.550 y = 8.429
x = 0.600 y = 8.431
x = 0.650 y = 8.432
x = 0.700 y = 8.433
x = 0.750 y = 8.435
x = 0.800 y = 8.436
x = 0.850 y = 8.438
x = 0.900 y = 8.439
x = 0.950 y = 8.440
```

Still not what you want, but I think the coding is far simpler.

Comment: Excelent, I like this suggestion. I've updated my code. The thing is that the results don't change. Maybe I've misunderstood the excel function and instead of 1E-13x6 being 1E-13*x^6 it could be something different?

Comment: Don't know.  This comment and your thoughts about that weird timestamp stuff suggest to me that you should dig deeper into Excel to figure out better what it's doing.  Only when you have that cold will you be able to translate it into Java.

Comment: I suggest you try with x = 0 and check it should be 8.414. If that's not right, nothing else will be.

Comment: thanks for your help with the code. Now it's obvious that my problem is either that the function I'm using isn't right, or the x values are wrong. So I'll keep looking. Thanks a lot for your help.